# IndexError: list index out of range if words[i+1] in vector: for c in range(len(vector)):

Tags: python

I have written some python code to vectorize data from a Text Corpus using a Word Frequency List. I am getting an IndexError: list index out of range error for this line of my code ;

```
if words[i+1] in vector:
                for c in range(len(vector)):
```

I am creating a code to Vectorize a Data Corpus from a Word Frequency List, the full code below:

```
# Process the original data, use a sliding window, convert the original data into vector form, and generate training samples.

def loadData():
    # Processing raw data
    data1 = open(r"ChinaCorpus.txt", 'r').read()
    data1 = data1.replace('[', '')
    data1 = data1.replace(']', '')
    words = data1.split()
    i = 0
    while i < len(words):           # Remove the previous date factor and reduce its impact on parameter adjustment
        if "1998" in words[i]:
            del words[i]
            i = i - 1
        i += 1
    lables = []
    print(len(words))
    for i in range(len(words)):
        t = words[i].find('/')
        lables.append(words[i][t:])
        words[i] = words[i][0:t]
    data2 = open(r"WordFreq.txt", "r",encoding= 'UTF-8').read()
    vector = data2.split()
    with open("VectorData.txt", "a", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for i in range(1,len(words)):
            flag = 0
            s = ""
            if words[i-1] in vector:
                for a in range(len(vector)):
                    if words[i-1] == vector[a]:
                        s += str(a)
                        s += ' '
                        break
            else:
                s += '0 '
            if words[i] in vector:
                for b in range(len(vector)):
                    if words[i] == vector[b]:
                        s += str(b)
                        s += ' '
                        if lables[i] == "/ns":
                            flag = 1
                        break
            else:
                s += '0 '
            if words[i+1] in vector:
                for c in range(len(vector)):
                    if words[i+1] == vector[c]:
                        s += str(c)
                        s += ' '
                        break
            else:
                s += '0 '
            if flag == 1:
                s += '1'
            else:
                s += '0'
            s += '\n'
            print(i)
            f.write(s)
    f.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loadData()
```

A screenshot of the error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/107Vs.png)

Comment: ``words[i+1]`` will give an error when ``words[len(words) + 1]`` occurs. Try using ``range(1, len(words) -1)`` instead

Comment: That was it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If vector contains 3 values, the counter will go through 0, 1, and 2. If you subtract 1 from 0 you get -1 which cannot be used in this case.

What I would suggest is to change it to something like

```
for i in [i for i in words if i in vector]:
    blabla
```

This iterates over the values in word in case it is also present in vector. If you want to compare the position of a word in each list, your approach works better of course.